# How to access object values using object["key"] approach

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, object

In the code I am referring, object attributes are accessed using the `object["key"]` method instead of calling `object.key` to access attribute values.
But when I try to create a simple object array and access attributes using above approach, I am getting below error.

```
if bank_record.effective_date.strip() == "25/07/2019" and bank_record["description"].__contains__("50036"):
TypeError: 'COM' object is not subscriptable
```

The reason given for object is not subscriptable error is missing `__getitem__` method for the class. But in the code I am referring, it doesn't contain such method for any of the dto classes. But the above `object["key"]` method works just fine. What am I missing. I have been trying to figure this out for a while.

I just want to loop through a object array and access object attributes and modify them on the run. In order to make the function generic, I want to access these object attributes using `object["key"]` approach. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I have missed set of steps. In the code I am referring, they are looping a json object array, which is created by dumping, python object array values into a json string and loaded back to a json object array.

```
excel_dto_list = []
#add objects to the list
#...
json_string = json.dumps([ob.__dict__ for ob in excel_dto_list])
#done in another method
downloaded_object = json.loads(json_string)
for x in downloaded_object:
    print(x["comment"])
```